# Doctrine partial select loads the whole object

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

From `MyEntityRepository`

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->select('partial e.{id, field0}')
;
echo $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();
```

Gives me

```sql
SELECT
  e0_.id AS id_0
, e0_.field0_0 AS field0_0
, e0_.field1_1 AS field1_1
, e0_.field2_2 AS field2_2
, -- ...
FROM my_entity e0_
```

**Why all my fields are selected ?**

*Same issue that [Doctrine partial queries return the complete object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497641), the difference is that I'm getting a wrong initial SQL.*

Comment: Try adding a query hint as described [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-hints) `->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true));`

Comment: I just saw that and it works. I'm wondering why do I have to do that since partial is already supposed to partially load the objects. Maybe because Doctrine has found them loaded in memory and bound them